# Zoomable android widget with VideoView component

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

There is compound widget which consists of `VideoView` and `Button`. `VideoView` play `video`, `Button` handle events. I'm struggling how to make it resizable according to pinch `gesture`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add pinch zoom to widgets, since there is no way to add event listeners to widgets. The only way a widget can receive input is assigning on click intents to different components, which start activities. As for videos, look into the `VideoView` class, although AFAIK this doesn't work well (if at all) with widgets.